# How can I link to a local image from my home screen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, home-screen-shortcuts, images

We are able to create a link to a website and put this link on our Home screen by using the `Add shortcut to home` inside the browser's context menu.

I would like to do the same for an image that is local to my phone, so that I can click on the button and have that particular image display.

How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually many ways  to achieve the goal.

#### Method 1

1. Install [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) -- I'm suggesting it because  I know that it provides a file widget.
2. In your default launcher, go to Widgets → choose **ES File Explorer** → locate and select the image you want to be launched by the shortcut, and it would be placed on your home screen now.

#### Method 2

You already know it.

Open your browser, enter `file:///` in the URL bar → locate to the folder where the image is located and then tap on it so that the browser should load it (show it, not download it) → use "Add shortcut to home" so that the shortcut can be created on the home screen.

**Note** that I tested this method on Firefox for Android and works well, but Chrome doesn't work.

#### Method 3

Find the activity responsible for showing the image in your default gallery app, input the data (image URI) into it, and use them in the [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to create a shortcut. (Use my [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/113923/96277) for *know-how*.)

Comment: Tested method 2 on native KitKat browser: the file is opened inside browser (if we talk about image) but if saved on home screen it cannot be opened, "Program is not installed" is showed, so this method is unusable, maybe except Firefox.