# Executing a script

Tags: scripts

I'm new to Android and trying to find the simplest way to run a 2 line script that deletes files from a specific directory.

I Googled the topic and created a file that I called `test.sh` which has 2 lines:

```
 #!/system/bin/sh
 delete Android/data/mydir/*.dmp
```

I copied this file to an Android device and managed to create a shortcut to this file. Now I want to execute this script whenever I click the shortcut but I'm unable to make it work!

I would appreciate any hints to get this going.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your device rooted? Does your device have busybox or toybox installed?
Is selinux enabled? If so you need to resolve these things, even after selinux may stop you so you will need to setenforce 0 and for that you need a build of busybox with selinux functions built in.

Comment: What do you mean by _unable to make it work_? Any error? Nothing happens? Have you done `chmod 755 test.sh`  after copying it to the phone?

Comment: You can use my answer for [Home screen icon for terminal program?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/113982) or [is there a way to run \*.sh file by just touching it in a file manager?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/113923) to execute the script from a shortcut.  However, is your script working from a shell? If not, then you should mention that in the question. Unless configured otherwise, shell would default to `/` directory and there is no `Android` directory at first level of `/`.

Comment: I managed to get the script to work inside the terminal emulator.  I had the path wrong; once I fixed that it worked.  I still am unable to create a shortcut because the launcher on the Android device (not a phone but a set top box) does not permit creating one.  I think I am going to just install Tasker although I was hoping I can find a simpler solution.  Thanks all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

In your script you forgot `#` , and what is more the command to **delete** is not `delete`(as you wrote) but `rm`, along with at least one option:

- `-r` for recursive
- `-f` for force
- `-v` for verbose

so try

**For a single file**

```
#!/system/bin/sh
rm /path/to/file/filename.extension
```

**For a group of files @ location by extension with wildcard:**

```
#!/system/bin/sh
rm /path/to/file/*.extension
```

**A straight up clearing of a directory:**

```
#!/system/bin/sh
rm /path/to/directory-containing-files/*
```

Alternate to **clear that directory of files and directories as well**, with verbose to see what's being deleted

```
#!/system/bin/sh
rm -frv /path/to/file/*
```

**To delete the directory itself**

```
#!/system/bin/sh
rm -fr /kill/that/pesky/directory
```

You must have `root` privileges  to modify anything in `/system` and/or `/data` folder.

The exception would be `/data/local` directory which you should be able to access/modify within as peon user.

If `selinux` is enforcing **you will NOT be able to modify anything** in `/data` with the exception of the previously stated exception even if `su`.

This with the exception of laying out the proper path to `sh` in your script is not really an android question.

**Your normal practices in scripting on a Linux OS should mostly carry over as long as you use the correct path to `sh`.**

You can create that script in regular `sdcard` storage space and execute by running

```
su    
/sdcard/./yams.sh
I like yams. They're nummy.
```

**If you get a permission error, denied etc.,** then

```
chmod 755 /path/to/script.sh
```

and again run as `su`

**You can alternately run**

```
su -c /sdcard/yams.sh
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the details... very helpful for a beginner! Followed all instructions but keep getting Permission denied when I try to run the script even though I did the chmod 755 and also trying against different subdirectories including /data/local!  I will keep at it!

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Script options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCiFx.jpg)

Has more privileges if you have a rooted phone
You can choose the script via the inbuilt file manager, and can choose various options, as seen[image: Script options]
And yes there's no command as delete Use

> rm -rf

instead as suggested [above](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/132741/132780)
Also if you are trying to delete the data created by an app i.e inside **data/data/example.app/DataToDelete**

You will need to have Superuser privileges or only that particular app can delete its own data.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury  thanks for the heads up, am new here

Comment: See info about [referencing](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). You don't appear to be the owner of that image. Whenever you use a work that helps answer a question, you must reference it and credit the author appropriately.